# SQL Update values from one table column to another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple select statement that identifies the rows I want to update. Basically i want to copy the vad_description to the vb_description and can't quite figure this out. Any Help would be appreciated.

```
    SELECT
  variant_bom.vb_id
 ,variant_bom.vb_description
 ,variant_detail.vad_description
FROM dbo.variant_bom
INNER JOIN dbo.variant_detail
  ON variant_bom.vb_vad_id = variant_detail.vad_id
INNER JOIN dbo.variant_setting
  ON variant_setting.vas_vad_id = variant_detail.vad_id
WHERE variant_setting.vas_manufactured_variant = 1
AND variant_setting.vas_discontinued_product = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
UPDATE vb
SET    vb.vb_description = vd.vad_description
FROM   dbo.variant_bom vb
       INNER JOIN dbo.variant_detail vd
               ON vb.vb_vad_id = vd.vad_id
       INNER JOIN dbo.variant_setting vs
               ON vs.vas_vad_id = vd.vad_id
WHERE  vs.vas_manufactured_variant = 1
       AND vs.vas_discontinued_product = 0
```

Giving `Alias` name to tables will make your query more readable

Comment: Wow. that was fast. +1

Comment: That was fast. I get the following response|
Error (1,1): String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @TowelsRus  What is the length of `variant_bom.vb_description` & `variant_detail.vad_description` column ?

Comment: Ah, I can see the issue there, 100 characters vs 250

Comment: @TowelsRus So you need to alter the length to 250 which should fix your problem